# Bus Stop Details

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to get bus stop details from the Google Places API. I have been able to get the actual bus stops but now I'd like to grab the details.

For example: This is the URL Google gives me from the response. https://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=14960400563022267569

I'd like to get a JSON representation of this information (if its available). Appending output=json just returns an empty json document.

Does anyone know how to grab the info without putting it through a parser?

EDIT: So continuing to dig through the flow I got SOME information from this URL but still doesn't seem to show me the bus numbers or anything. http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=14960400563022267569&q=a&output=json

Answer (score 5):

Currently, there seems to be no option in google apis to retrieve the public transit information the way you are seeing on google maps. Your best bet is to use **google places api** and to filter for bus_station to get details about the bus stations , but the information returned will be limited these [result details](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsResults) . Another option is to use **google directions api**, where you can search for directions by keeping your bus station as the source and a suitable destination and the returned results will provide some [transit details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TransitDetails) which include departure time, headways, etc.